# Prime factor of larger numbers by hand/simple calculator $12402^5$

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Trying to work out a prime number factorization (preparing myself for an upcoming exam).

We have worked a bit with prime number factorization and $\gcd$ during this semester.

I know how to approach factoring out a number that around $12402$ by hand/simple calculator  (casio fx-82ex).

But how would I approach something like factoring $ 12402^5$? This will end up as $(2.933990039*10^{20})$ on my calculator making it hard to for example look on the last three digits and see what they are dividable by.

Are there any best practices in approaching a number of this size?

Regards,
Petter

Comment: you just have to factor $12402$.

Comment: $$
12~402 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 13 \times 53
$$
$$
\Rightarrow (12~402)^5 =\left( 2 \times 3^2 \times 13 \times 53 \right)^5 = \ldots
$$

Comment: Just for completion : removing the $2$, you get $6201$. You can remove $9$ using the divisibility test to get $689$. Then checking divisibility by smaller primes in increasing order gives $13$  as a factor, so we get $2 \times 9 \times 13 \times 53$. as the final factorization (via completely mental mathematics). Now you can use the hints given to get the factorization of $(12402)^5$. However, suppose you have a large number that is not a power of a smaller number e.g. $97346111$, then you have an issue. Why, even the much smaller $4661$ offers a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I was not aware of this. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the prime factorisation of $n$ is $$n = p_1^{e_1}\ldots p_r^{e_r},$$ then we have $$n^5=p_1^{5e_1}\ldots p_r^{5e_r}.$$

Comment: Alright, that's interesting. So only the "n" is calculated and then I just move over the exponent? So I would end up with $ (2*3^2*13*53)^5 $?

Comment: @PetterÖstergren The $n$ isn't calculated, per se, it's the number you plug in, in this case 12402. If you mean its prime decomposition is calculated, then yes, that is the hard part. The point is that you write the original number as a product of primes, and when you take the fifth power you can rearrange the order of multiplication to group powers of each given prime $p_i$ together and produce the prime factorisation for $n^5$.

Comment: I understood that n = 12402 in this case. But the clarification helpt for sure! Appreciate it!